# Not able to insert the data from url to database in php

Tags: php, mysql

**final.php**

Here I am trying to get the data from the url using GET method and trying to insert into the database. I was able to insert the data for first few rows after that the data is not inserted. Can anyone help me regarding this?

when I try to run the url: `www.myii.com/app/final.php?name=123&glucose=3232...`
the data is not inserting.

```
 <?php 
include("query_connect.php");

$name = $_GET['name'];
$glucose = $_GET['glucose'];
$temp = $_GET['temp'];

$battery = $_GET['battery'];
$tgs_a = $_GET['tgs_a'];
$tgs_g = $_GET['tgs_g'];
$heartrate = $_GET['heartrate'];
$spo2 = $_GET['spo2'];
$rr = $_GET['rr'];
$hb = $_GET['hb'];
$ina22 = $_GET['ina22'];
$accucheck = $_GET['accucheck'];
$isactive = $_GET['isactive'];
$address = $_GET['address'];
$deviceno = $_GET['deviceno'];

$sql_insert = "insert into query (name,glucose,temp,battery,tgs_a,tgs_g,heartrate,spo2,rr,hb,ina22,accucheck,isactive,address,deviceno) values ('$name','$glucose','$temp',$battery','$tgs_a','$tgs_g','$heartrate','$spo2','$rr','$hb','$ina22','$accucheck','$isactive','$address','$deviceno')";

mysqli_query($sql_insert);

if($sql_insert)
{
    echo "Saving succeed";
    //echo $date_time;
}
else{
    echo "Error occured";
}
```

?>

**Query_connect.php**

This is my database config php file.

```
    <?php 
$user = "m33root";
$password = "me3i434";
$host = "localhost";

$connection = mysqli_connect($host,$user,$password);
$select = mysqli_select_db('miiyy',$connection);

if($connection)
{
    echo "connection succesfull<br>";
}
else {
    echo "Error";
}
```

?>

Comment: Use MySQLi or PDO.

Comment: does it make difference if i use just mysql?? starting few times i was able to insert the data.. and now the data is not getting inserted

Comment: **MySQL extension was deprecated in PHP 5.5.0, and it was removed in PHP 7.0.0. Instead, the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extension should be used**

Comment: ok i will try that..thank you

Comment: Replace your new code and DB structure

Comment: Change `mysql_query` too

Comment: `query` is a reserved word in mysql: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/keywords.html you must quote it.

Comment: I have changed it.. still same

Comment: @PrajwalKM check the asnwer

Comment: Hi there, try displaying $sql_insert; that is your query and execute it in your phpmyadmin. Then depending upon the the message you can know the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that all columns can contain NULL so that not filled fields will stay NULL instead of throwing an error.

Comment: I have used id as my primary key

Answer (score 0):

Try these

**In SQL**

1. Change the table name of `query` to some other name. Because "[query](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/keywords.html)" is reserved in SQL

**In code**

```
if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql_insert ))
{
    echo("Error description: " . mysqli_error($con));
}
else
{
    echo "Success";
}
```

[Use `mysqli_error()` function](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_error.asp)

Comment: ok i will try changing table name.. also i am getting error descriotion now

Comment: Hello sir... can you please help me to solve this issue.... here is the link..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37967017/how-to-trim-first-three-characters-based-on-the-first-letterexpression-before

Answer (score 0):

Try below to see mysql error:

```
 mysql_query($sql_insert);
echo mysql_error()
```